# How to use Java in a Matlab GUIDE?

Tags: java, matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I'm trying to do a multi-line editbox uicontrol like explained [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-listbox-editbox-scrollbars/) but I can't get this working in my GUIDE.

```
function listbox_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to message_list (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

  % Get the Java scroll-pane container reference
  jScrollPane = findjobj(listbox);

  % Modify the scroll-pane's scrollbar policies
  set(jScrollPane,'VerticalScrollBarPolicy',20);  % VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED
  set(jScrollPane,'HorizontalScrollBarPolicy',31);  % HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER
```

Any sugestion?

Comment: What line is failing? Do you get an exception? If so, what is the `message`?

Comment: «The name 'VerticalScrollBarPolicy' is not an accessible property for an instance of class
'com.mathworks.hg.peer.ListboxPeer$UicontrolList'.»

Comment: How is `listbox` defined? Is it a `uicontrol('style','edit')` edit box like in the link you provided or are you doing something else? I get your error when I try a different style, e.g. `'listbox'`. In that case `jScrollPane` ends up being a vector of handles and the first and third don't cause errors.

Comment: @horchler The code I posted is the code generated by GUIDE where I inserted a listbox. Maybe the problem is the place where I have my code, I don't know because it is not clear how to do that using GUIDEs.

Comment: I changed 'listbox' to 'editbox' and now it's working. I was missing the 'max' value too.